# How to change height of a dynamically embedded gist?

Tags: css, github, gist

How to change height of a dynamically embedded gist?

I have tried a lot of different ways using css and I can't seem to figure out how to change the height of the gist to where it has scrollbars.

Gist call

```
$.getJSON("https://gist.github.com/username/my_gist.json?callback=?", function(result){
    $('div.container').append('<div class="row slide sub-slide-1"><div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-8">' + result.div + '</div></div>');
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + result.stylesheet + '"/>');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Just did this and works fine. You can also apply it on `.gist`, works the same

```
.container{
 height: 150px;
 overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```

### [View Demo](http://jsbin.com/fanikuruwe/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: The code works perfect. As stated the issue is setting the height of the gist. I think I may have narrowed it down to .gist { display:table } in the gist stylesheet but I am not hundred percent sure yet. Haven't worked with table in css before.

Comment: I'm an idiot.. my bad. Just update it and it works with scroll as well.

Comment: thank you, the overflow-y: scroll is what I needed. Can't believe I didn't try that......